# Finding a Real Number using epslion

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, absolute-value

Fix a real number $x$ and $\epsilon>0$. If $|x-1|\le \epsilon$ show $|2-x|\ge 1- \epsilon$

I think we were supposed to use the triangle inequality to show this.

If we use the triangle inequality then $|x-1|\le ||x|-|1||$ so then $x\le \epsilon+1$ so then $-x\ge-\epsilon-1$ adding 2 to each side we get $2-x\ge 1-\epsilon$

does that make sense?

Comment: Your statement of the triangle inequality not right. The right statement of triangle inequality is $|x+y|\le |x|+|y|$. If you reverse the inequality in your statement then it is also true and is called *reverse* triangle inequality.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if $a,b\in\mathbb C$ then $$\big||a|-|b|\big|\leqslant |a|-|b|. $$
For
$$|a| \leqslant |a-b| + |b|\implies |a|-|b|\leqslant|a-b| $$
and similarly
$$|b| \leqslant |a-b| + |a|\implies |a|-|b|\leqslant|a-b|.$$

Answer (score 0):

I would argue by cases based on the value of $x$.  If $x \ge 2$, you are to show $x-1\le \epsilon \implies x-2 \ge 1-\epsilon$  Add $1$ to each side and use $\epsilon \gt 0$ and you are there.  You have two more cases, $x \in [1,2)$ and $x \lt 1$